# Convert pandas series of lists to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series made of lists

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

and I want a DataFrame with each column a list.

None of `from_items`, `from_records`, `DataFrame` `Series.to_frame` seem to work.

How to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As @Hatshepsut pointed out in the comments, `from_items` is [deprecated as of version 0.23](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_items.html). The link suggests to use `from_dict` instead, so the old answer can be modified to:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(s.index, s.values)))
```

--------------------------------------------------OLD ANSWER-------------------------------------------------------------

You can use `from_items` like this (assuming that your lists are of the same length):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(s.index, s.values))

   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(s.index, s.values)).T

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

depending on your desired output.

This can be much faster than using an `apply` (as used in [@Wen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901030/1534017) which, however, does also work for lists of different length):

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(s.index, s.values))
1000 loops, best of 3: 669 µs per loop

%timeit s.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x)).T
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop
```

and

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(s.index, s.values)).T
1000 loops, best of 3: 919 µs per loop

%timeit s.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop
```

Also [@Hatshepsut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901040/1534017) is quite fast (also works for lists of different length):

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(item for item in s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 636 µs per loop
```

and

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(item for item in s).T
1000 loops, best of 3: 884 µs per loop
```

Fastest solution seems to be [@Abdou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901240/1534017) (tested for Python 2; also works for lists of different length; use `itertools.zip_longest` in Python 3.6+):

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame.from_records(izip_longest(*s.values))
1000 loops, best of 3: 529 µs per loop
```

An additional option:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(s.index, s.values)))

   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: In case you'd like to add it, @Abdou's `itertools` solution seems to be even faster. but does require that additional library. Might also note the same-length restriction where that applies?

Comment: @Hatshepsut: Added. Same length does not seem to be required, also works fine for `s = pd.Series([[1,2, 3,4], [4, 5,6]])`

Comment: Why write `s.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x))` when we could just write `s.apply(pd.Series)`? :)

Comment: @KirillG: I took this from [Wen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901030/1534017) for speed comparisons.

Comment: `from_items` is [now deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_items.html)

Comment: For the sake of simplicity and readability, I suggest changing the answer to: `pd.DataFrame(s.to_dict())`

Answer (score 13):

If the length of the series is super high (more than 1m), you can use:

```
s = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist())
```

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(s))
```

Comment: This method is much faster than Cleb's one. Nice.

Answer (score 8):

Iterate over the series like this:

```
series = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
pd.DataFrame(item for item in series)

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Comment: Quite fast; should add this to the timings below... (upvoted)

Answer (score 7):

[`pd.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_records) should also work using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

pd.DataFrame.from_records(zip_longest(*s.values))

#    0  1
# 0  1  4
# 1  2  5
# 2  3  6
```

Comment: Seem to be the fastest solution (upvoted). You might want to add that this is a Python3 solution; in Python 2 it would be `itertools.izip_longest`.

Answer (score 3):

You may looking for

```
s.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x))
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Or

```
 s.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x)).T

Out[133]: 
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: Might not be the best choice here as it seems rather slow (see my timings below).

Comment: @Cleb try this example `s = pd.Series([[1,2, 3,4], [4, 5,6]])` I consider the different length of the list ~if it  is the same length your answer is better ~ :)

Comment: Sure, then mine will fail, but Hatshepsut's still seems faster. I indeed assumed that all lists have the same length, will add this as a comment, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

**Note** that the `from_items()` method in the accepted answer is **deprecated** in the latest Pandas and `from_dict()` method should be used instead. Here is how:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(s.index, s.values)))

## OR  

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(s.index, s.values))).T
```

Also note that using `from_dict()` provides us with the **fastest** approach so far:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(s.index, s.values)))
376 µs ± 14.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

## OR

%timeit pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(s.index, s.values))).T
487 µs ± 3.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: does `from_records` change anything about this answer?

Answer (score 0):

a better approach is to use the fact that pandas outputs a numpy array when using `Series.values`.
You can then reshape this weird collection of collections into a stack of records using `np.vstack` which will automatically unpack all the data into a neat n_row x n_cols shaped numpy array.

```py
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(my_serie.values), index=my_serie.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is the *transpose* property.

- [Pandas - .T property](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_records(s).T
```

This is the output generated from the above code.

```
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```