# How to separate column into 3 columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to separate a column value into 3 columns by removing the brackets from below data. But I am unable to separate. I am using below code in python to separate.

```
Point:
(48.1371079, 11.5753822, 0.0)
(51.5142273, 7.4652789, 0.0)
(51.3406321, 12.3747329, 0.0)
```

Expected output

```
Lat        Long       Point
48.1371079 11.5753822 0.0
51.5142273 7.4652789  0.0
51.3406321 12.3747329 0.0
```

Code I tried:

```
data[['Lat', 'Long', 'Point']] = data.point.str.split(", ",expand=True)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-35ce2b258b1f> in <module>
----> 1 data[['Lat', 'Long', 'Point']] = data.point.str.split(", ",expand=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2933             self._setitem_frame(key, value)
   2934         elif isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, list, Index)):
-> 2935             self._setitem_array(key, value)
   2936         else:
   2937             # set column

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _setitem_array(self, key, value)
   2959             if isinstance(value, DataFrame):
   2960                 if len(value.columns) != len(key):
-> 2961                     raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
   2962                 for k1, k2 in zip(key, value.columns):
   2963                     self[k1] = value[k2]

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Comment: Looks like your column has tuples as the values. How'd you get it into the DataFrame in the first place? Might make more sense to fix it there.

Comment: Hi ALollz, I have created data['point'] column using `data['point'] = data['location'].apply(lambda loc: tuple(loc.point) if loc else None)`

Comment: is your data a string or tuple?   answer will be different

Comment: If `Point` is a tuple, you should be able to just use `df[['Lat', 'Lon', 'Point']] = pd.DataFrame(df.Point.tolist())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to convert a series of tuples to a data frame (i.e., to expand the tuples):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Point':
[(48.1371079, 11.5753822, 0.0),
(51.5142273, 7.4652789, 0.0),
(51.3406321, 12.3747329, 0.0),]})

# expand
df = df['Point'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, index=('X', 'Y', 'Z')))
print(df)

           X          Y    Z
0  48.137108  11.575382  0.0
1  51.514227   7.465279  0.0
2  51.340632  12.374733  0.0
```

Using apply / Series was obtained from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901030/13608599

Answer (score 0):

If `Point:` is the `index`, try this:

```
data = data.reset_index()

for i in list(data.columns):
    data[i] = (data[i]
             .str.replace(',', '')
             .str.replace(' ', '')
             .str.replace('(', '')
             .str.replace(')', ''))

data = data.rename(columns=({
    'level_0': 'Lat',
    'level_1': 'Long',
    'Point:': 'Point'
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['point'].tolist(), index=df.index)
print(df)

           0          1    2
0  48.137108  11.575382  0.0
1  51.514227   7.465279  0.0
2  51.340632  12.374733  0.0
```

Comment: Hi, This is working as expected. Can you please explain how this works.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a string,  need three match groups.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Point
(48.1371079, 11.5753822, 0.0)
(51.5142273, 7.4652789, 0.0)
(51.3406321, 12.3747329, 0.0)"""), sep="\n")

df[['Lat', 'Long', 'Point']] = df["Point"].str.extract(r"^\(([0-9.]*), ([0-9.]*), ([0-9.]*)\)$", expand=True)
```

#### tuple

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Point': (48.1371079, 11.5753822, 0.0)},
 {'Point': (51.5142273, 7.4652789, 0.0)},
 {'Point': (51.3406321, 12.3747329, 0.0)}])

df.assign(
    Lat=df["Point"].apply(lambda r: r[0]),
    Long=df["Point"].apply(lambda r: r[1]),
    Point=df["Point"].apply(lambda r: r[2]),
)
```